# an error occured while the batch was being executed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a simple table in a database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[klanten]
(
    [Klant_naam] TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Klant_adres] TEXT NULL, 
    [klant_gsm] TEXT NULL, 
    [klant_gewicht] INT NOT NULL, 
    [klant_lengte] INT NOT NULL, 
    [klant_klacht] TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

When I try to update it, the following error pops-up.

[image: The error]

Comment: Look at the picture for more information.

Error : an errer occurd while the batch was being executed

Comment: "An error occurred" - yes, but we can't see what error.

Comment: Unless you have a generic ANSI SQL question, please tag the question to reflect the database you are using.

Comment: it's a serice based-database

Comment: (66,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Klant_naam' in table 'klanten' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) warns:

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

So, try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[klanten] (
    [Klant_naam] varchar(max) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Klant_adres] varchar(max)  NULL, 
    [klant_gsm] varchar(max)  NULL, 
    [klant_gewicht] INT NOT NULL, 
    [klant_lengte] INT NOT NULL, 
    [klant_klacht] varchar(max)  NOT NULL
)
```

Well, this doesn't quite work either, because there is a limit of 900 bytes for index keys.  How about using a surrogate key and reasonable column lengths?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[klanten] (
    Klant_Id int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
    [Klant_naam] varchar(255) NOT NULL unique, 
    [Klant_adres] varchar(max)  NULL, 
    [klant_gsm] varchar(max)  NULL, 
    [klant_gewicht] INT NOT NULL, 
    [klant_lengte] INT NOT NULL, 
    [klant_klacht] varchar(max)  NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "TEXT" data type to "NCHAR()" or any other similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occured when you try to update database, but some fields can't be updated. For example, I have 5 fields in a table:

```
[Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Path]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Name]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Url]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[SecureUrl]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL
```

I've worked for some time with it, and make some records. And some of them have value NULL at [Url]. Suddenly I decide to change table:

```
[Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Path]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Name]         NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Url]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, //!!! HERE A PROBLEM, I ALREADY HAVE NULL RECORDS IN DATA
[SecureUrl]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL
```

Problem is that my data has been made with the old model and it has records with the NULL at [Url], but in new model NULL value can't be at [Url]. So as with new model, old data can't be correct. Thus we have the error when update.